# JSP Compilation Issue

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am working on a Java web application that was worked upon by somebody else earlier and this person just provided me the source code of the application. The problem is if I try to make some changes to this application and deploy it on tomcat (7.0.35) the JSPs do not render and I get the following error:

[image: JSP Compilation Error]

Additionally, I notice that the class file for this welcome.jsp is not created.

The only way I can get the app working is re-installing new version of tomcat and then building, deploying and accessing the original source code. When I build and deploy that code, and access the JSPs they compile properly and also .class and .java files get created in the tomcat work directory.

After this I copy paste all my changes to the original source code and redeploy the modified app and it works fine because the class and java files corresponding to the JSP pages were created after deploying and accessing the original application.

Also, if I try to modify the JSPs, the same error starts appearing.

I have no clue what is going wrong here.It would be great if some one can please help me with this. The JDK version that I am using is 1.6.0_38-b05. Tomcat also points to the same JDK version and I do not have any other version of JDK or JRE installed on my computer.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@page import="com.xyz.toolkit.utils.FormConstant"%>
    <%@page import="org.jasig.cas.client.util.AbstractCasFilter"%>
    <%@page import="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Assertion"%>
    <%@page import="org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionHolder"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/AccessValidateHandlerTag.tld" prefix="toolkit"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ToolKit</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html CHARSET=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery.ui.tabs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/migration_toolkit.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js">         </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/commons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

    <link href="css/jquery.jqplot.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <%
    String roleAdmin = FormConstant.ROLE_ADMIN + "," + FormConstant.ROLE_ALL;
String roleUser = FormConstant.ROLE_USER + "," + FormConstant.ROLE_ALL;
    %>
    <body>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<div id="tabs">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <div id="welcome_msg">
            Welcome
            <%=session.getAttribute(FormConstant.USER_NAME)%>
        </div>
        <div id="logoutBTN">
            <button id="logoutButton" onclick="javascript:loadFeedBack();">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="feedbackForm">
        <form method="POST" action="logout" class="box tableBox">
            <div class="form_field">
                <div class="box_body">
                    Thank you for using the Migration Toolkit. Please enter
                    any feedback you may have and tell us how you would like us to
                    improve the user experience.
                </div>
            </div>
            <p style="clear: both"></p>
            <div class="form_field" class="box_body">
                <div class="box_body">
                    <label for="projectName">User Name :</label> <input type="text"
                        value="<%=session.getAttribute(FormConstant.USER_NAME)%>"
                        disabled /> <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName"
                        value="<%=session.getAttribute(FormConstant.USER_NAME)%>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <p style="clear: both"></p>
            <div class="form_field">
                <div class="box_body">
                    <label for="projectName">User Feedback:</label>
                    <textarea id="userFeedBack" name="userFeedBack"
                        style="width: 450px; height:250px"></textarea>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p style="clear: both"></p>
            <div class="form_field">
                <div class="box_body">
                    <label for="submitFeedback">&nbsp;</label>
                    <button id="submitFeedback" type="submit" style="float: right;">Submit Feedback</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <toolkit:AccessValidateHandlerTag group="<%=roleAdmin%>">
            <li><a href="pages/generateRule.jsp">Review & Generate
                    Rulesets</a></li>
        </toolkit:AccessValidateHandlerTag>
        <toolkit:AccessValidateHandlerTag group="<%=roleUser%>">
            <li><a href="pages/codeParser.jsp">Parse a Codebase</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/reportViewer.jsp">Generate Consolidated Report</a></li>
        </toolkit:AccessValidateHandlerTag>
    </ul>

</div>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the Tomcat Config:Using CATALINA_BASE:

```
    "C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
    Using JAVA_OPTS:       " -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Users\kinjal.doshi\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\logging.properties" -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
```

[image]

Comment: can you please put the code here of your welcome.jsp

Comment: may be you havent kept the jsp jar file in your class path , please check if the jar are available in your classpath

Comment: how are you actually deploying and how are you building? have you considered building it as a war? do you use maven or similar tools?

Comment: Yes using Maven to build the war am deploying the war by keeping it in tomcats webapp folder ans starting tomcat

Comment: @Hussain - All required jars are available in the class path

Comment: Stack trace is not visible

Answer (score 0):

You are precompiling your JSPs using JspC from an old version of Tomcat and trying to run them on a newer version. Generally JspC from one major version of Tomcat will work with any other release from the same major version but that isn't guaranteed. To be sure of correct compilation, you need to use JspC from the same version of Tomcat as you intend to run on.

Comment: I Have never used JspC, could you please help me understand how I can identify that JspC is being used. I am not doing any command line pre-compilation so not sure how to go about with this.

Comment: Also, how can I avoid pre-compiling JSPs and let this be taken care of at deploy time and later?

Comment: I read a little about JspC and checked pom.xml of my application. There is no task added for precompiling JSPs. I have also checked web.xml, precompile feature is not used there as well and what I do not understand is that the original project works fine when I build and deploy it whereas when I build and deploy a modified version of the project, the same does not work on the same version of tomcat and jdk. This seems a little weird. Would be glad if you could please shed more light on this matter

Comment: The first error in the screenshot is triggered when a JSP is converted to a .java file using one version of Tomcat and then compiled to a .class file using s different version. Using JspC is the most common way to do that. If you are sure you aren't using the JspC task at all then it is possible there is another cause. Looking at the other errors, your environment is seriously messed up as it appears neither Map nor HashMap support generics which they should in Java 6.

Comment: Right! But What I don't understand is that how come the same JSPs in the original version of the application work fine when build and deployed on the same version of JDK and Tomcat? This is what I can't figure out basically; am sure that JspC is not used at all.

Comment: Just added tomcat configurations to the original post. You can see that the same JDK version is used with tomcat that is used while building the app. There is one more point I noticed, when JSPs are compiled, the _java and .class files in work directory have the same timestamp as the dates of the JSP (30/04/32013). Is that normal?

Comment: There is no evidence that the same JDK version or the same Tomcat version is used when building the app and when running it. The timestamps being the same is intentional as is made clear in the comment at the start of the .java file.

Comment: I have added a snapshot to the original show which version of JDK is used by mvn for build and by tomcat's catalina script when the server starts. Again both versions are same and what I don't understand is when I am building and deploying the original app, the same versions are used as shown in the snapshot. In that case, the JSPs compile but now when I modify any part of the code and do a build and deploy the JSPs fail to compile. This does not make sense to me somehow.