# Unable to complie class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting this error in MyEclipse and working on Struts 2 framework

**Exception:**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 17 in the generated java file The return
>   type is incompatible with JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

**Stacktrace:**

```
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:423)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: This maybe caused by jar conflict.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of jsp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 7 fails to compile JSP Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552244/tomcat-7-fails-to-compile-jsp-pages)