# Jasper Exception when using Tomcat 9

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, exception

I've been tasked with migrating a site from one institution to another.  As part of the process we are attempting to update the versions the site uses.

Initially I was asked to use Java 8 with Tomcat 5.5 (on Linux), which led to issues.  I have since tried to deploy the webapps to Tomcat 9 with Java 8.  Some of the webapps appear to run fine (and resolve the issues I was having with Tomcat5).  However, the main app throws a JasperException when I go to the index.jsp
- the same web app deployed to Tomcat 5.5 loads without issue.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type index_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceImports.getPackageImports()

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type index_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceImports.getClassImports()

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type index_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Long>

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved to a variable

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type HashSet is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

An error occurred at line: [30] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [31] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [32] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [33] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_classes cannot be resolved to a variable

An error occurred at line: [39] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, Long>

An error occurred at line: [40] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_dependants cannot be resolved to a variable

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [44] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved to a variable

An error occurred at line: [47] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [48] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat9/work/Catalina/localhost/home/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_classes cannot be resolved to a variable

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:345)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    edu.purdue.cybercenter.ionomics.servlet.PiiMS.doGet(PiiMS.java:83)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Most of the similar issues I have found have suggested this would be related to the jar files and possibly some sort of conflict.  However, the lib structure for tomcat 9 is different to tomcat5 and I'm not sure which jars could be causing this.  I've also tried changing the index.jsp into a simpler (HelloWorld) form - removing any code, with the same Exception thrown.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and/or have any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Some of the links/suggestions I've tried so far:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552244/tomcat-7-fails-to-compile-jsp-pages

Clearing out work directory didn't help either:
http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/072v2kf60h/java-permission-denied-error-in-tomcat
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201503.mbox/%3CCABzHfVmfcPXqGdkj9jES4OCQMd+U45JLDqMzMb-kSEg8xEOvYw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Did you copy any of the "generated" files from your Tomcat 5-era installation into the Tomcat 8/8/5/9 installation? Specifically, any of the .java files that were built from your `.jsp` files? Those generated files are not portable between versions of Tomcat (sometimes even point-releases within the same version). If you stop Tomcat, completely delete the `work` directory and restart Tomcat, does that resolve anything?

Comment: Nothing should be deployed onto Tomcat 5 anymore. Tomcat 7 is the minimum reasonable version for anyone to use for anything these days. Tomcat 8.5 would be the best choice if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the interest and tips Christopher.  

I didn't copy any files between tomcat5 and tomcat9.  I have also tried deleting the the work directory and restarting tomcat which didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Sorry you are having issues. since this is likely to be a protracted investigation/discussion, might I suggest that you join the [Tomcat users' mailing](https://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) list and re-post your question there? SO might not be the right forum for you to get help in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, it looks like the problem was a number of libraries in the application's `WEB-INF/lib` directory that really needed to be removed, including:

- `rt.jar`
- `servlet-api.jar`

I'm answering this question *and* recommending that it be closed as it was a "simple mistake", but some readers may find it useful to see what the resolution actually was.

Comment: Specifically it was the rt.jar that was causing the issues.