# JSP compilation exception after Tomcat upgrade to 8.5.51 from 7.0.59

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have upgraded tomcat version to `8.5.51` from `7.0.59`. After this upgrade I am getting below exception when trying to access index.jsp page.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
The type index_005f_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceImports.getPackageImports()

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
The type index_005f_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceImports.getClassImports()

An error occurred at line: [38] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [40] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved to a variable

An error occurred at line: [44] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
_jspx_imports_packages cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [64] in the generated java file:
[/home/application_path/work/org/apache/jsp/index_005f_jsp.java]
The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:552)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:381)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:597)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at ActiveServerPkg.ActiveServer.doPost2(ActiveServer.java:1004)
        at ActiveServerPkg.ActiveServer.doPost(ActiveServer.java:253)
        at ActiveServerPkg.ActiveServer.doGet(ActiveServer.java:245)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Difference between generated servlet files

***with tomcat 7.0.59***

```
public final class index_005f_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {
```

***with tomcat  8.5.51***

```
public final class index_005f_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent,
                 org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports {
```

**JspSourceImports** interface got added in implements list

I thought it might be due change in code/syntax backward compatibility in version so replaced my index.jsp content with simply **Hello World** message but still facing same issue.

Original JSP content can't be shared due to org policy issues, modified jsp look likes below where I am able to reproduce this issue.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

java version used is `openjdk version 1.8.0_212`

[image: Tomcat and Java version details]

***Jars from tomcat lib folder...***
[image: Jars from tomcat lib folder]

***List of jars which are available in my WEB-INF/lib folder***

```
activation.jar                                  jackson-annotations-2.10.2.ja   ribbon-2.7.17.jar             
antlr-complete-3.5.2.jar                        jackson-core-2.10.2.jar         ribbon-archaius-2.7.17.jar    
aopalliance-1.0.jar                             jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar     ribbon-core-2.7.17.jar        
apache.jar                                      jai_codec.jar                   ribbon-loadbalancer-2.7.17.jar
archaius-core-0.7.6.jar                         jai_core.jar                    ribbon-transport-2.7.17.jar
aspectj-maven-plugin-1.7.jar                    javassist-3.3.jar               security.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar                         javax.batch-api-1.0.jar         servo-core-0.10.1.jar
avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar               javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar     servo-internal-0.10.1.jar
batik.jar                                       jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar   slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
bcprov-jdk16-145.jar                            jce1_2_2.jar                    slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
bsf-2.4.0.jar                                   jcert.jar                       smtp.jar
cglib-3.1.jar                                   jdbc.jar                        spring-aop-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar                          jettison-1.3.7.jar              spring-aspects-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar                   jnet.jar                        spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
commons-configuration-1.8.jar                   js.jar                          spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar                            jta-1.1.jar                     spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.SONATYPE.jar             local_policy.jar                spring-context-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar                            log4j-1.2.17.jar                spring-context-support-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar                         logback-classic-1.0.12.jar      spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-net-3.5.jar                             logback-core-1.0.12.jar         spring-expression-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar                          mailapi.jar                     spring-jdbc-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-jce-api.jar                             mail.jar                        spring-orm-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-jce-compat.jar                          micrometer-core-1.1.5.jar       spring-oxm-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-jce-provider.jar                        mlibwrapper_jai.jar             spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-message-api.jar                         mybatis-3.2.4.jar               spring-tx-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-openpgp-provider.jar                    mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar        spring-web-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar
cryptix-pki-api.jar                             netflix-commons-util-0.1.1.jar  sunjce_provider.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                                 netflix-statistics-0.1.1.jar    tag_gen.jar
fop.jar                                         ojdbc7.jar                      tomcat-jdbc-9.0.22.jar
guava-19.0.jar                                  ostermillerutils_1_07_00.jar    velocity-1.6.2.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar   poi-3.17.jar                    xalan200.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar                 poi-ooxml-3.17.jar              xerces-2.4.0.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.1.9.Final.jar               poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar      xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar             pop3.jar                        xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
imap.jar                                        quartz-2.2.1.jar                XmlSchema-1.2.jar
j2ssh.jar                                       quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar           xstream-1.4.11.1.jar
```

Cleared work directory as well but no luck :(

Also tried solutions from below links but still not working.

[Jasper Exception when using Tomcat 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115899/jasper-exception-when-using-tomcat-9)

[JSP compilation fails with Tomcat 8.0.20. Works with 8.0.11](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201503.mbox/%3CCABzHfVmfcPXqGdkj9jES4OCQMd+U45JLDqMzMb-kSEg8xEOvYw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: 1. Did you clean your `work` and `temp` directories? 2. How do your problematic JSPs look like? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: do you use precompiled JSPs?

Comment: @OlafKock 1. I tried creating work and temp directories but still issue exist. 2. Original JSP content I can not share due to organization policies, so I tried with new JSP having content only 'hello world' and was able to reproduce issue. I'll try to create and share reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: @areus - no, JSP's get compiled run-time only.

Comment: could you post a failing JSP?

Comment: @areus, edited original question with jsp. Thank you.

Comment: I would doublecheck that Tomcat is really using JDK 1.8. Some log errors like this: `The type Set is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>` suggest it is running on an older JDK

Comment: Or you are putting some core JAR libraries on WEB-INF/lib that shouldn't be there

Comment: @areus, I have not added core JAR libraries in WEB-INF/lib folder and also added image with Apache Tomcat and its JVM version details in question. Thank you.

Comment: If not in your WEB-INF/lib, some JAR added to Tomcat is messing things.

Comment: @areus, updated question with jars from tomcat lib folder. Thanks.

Comment: Could you access `http://localhost:8080` and see if the JSP examples work? If the do, then is something in your webapp, if they don't is something general with your tomcat installation.

Comment: @areus, Another JSP example I already tried with same tomcat and it's working fine, I also feel the problem is with my webapp but not able to identify the cause, had gone through number of jars which are there in WEB-INF/lib but not able to spot issue. No core jars from tomcat or java in my webapp lib.

Comment: may be some jar related to jasper or ecj?

Comment: @areus, I think I don't have any jasper/ecj jar on WEB-INF/lib folder, updated question with all the available jars in lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, one of the library(jar) from *application's WEB-INF/lib* directory was causing this issue and the jar is...

```
cryptix-jce-compat.jar
```

After removing *cryptix-jce-compat.jar* from lib folder, JSP compilation started working with latest tomcat version(8.5.51) as it was working earlier in older tomcat version(7.0.59).